# Perl Returning error for ls -l command

Tags: perl, nagios, nagiosxi

I am running a perl script from Nagios to check some files for certain characteristics on a windows machine.  When I run the script from Nagios it responds with a result of:

> UNKNOWN ERROR - execution of LANG=C ls -l resulted in an error 32512 -

My Code is [from this GitHub](https://github.com/willixix/naglio-plugins/blob/master/check_files.pl) with a single modification of line 168 so I can use it with windows:

```
use lib 'C$\Progra~1\Nagios\NRDS_Win\plugins';
```

The odd thing is the program actually outputs the expected result from the command line on the windows machine.

Here is the command:

> check_files.pl -D c:\logs -F Health.log -a '~,300'

Here is an example:

> CRITICAL - Health.log  is 10703 (more than 300) seconds old - 1
>   Health.log files found

I modified line that defined `LANG=C ls -l` in the code but now i just get:

> UNKNOWN ERROR - could not execute ls -l - No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

`ls` is unix command and by default there is no such command in windows.

If you need it, you can install it e.g. from [GNU CoreUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)

You also need to change shell command on line 639 from `LANG=C ls -l` to just `ls -l` because in windows you can't set environment variables like that.

Comment: Even if they did, `LANG=C ls -l` would still be an invalid Windows command

Comment: 'ls' is on the windows box and I did change the LANG=C line to just be ls -l but I still get an:  UNKNOWN ERROR - could not execute ls -l - No such file or directory  in nagios but if I run the same command from the command prompt it works fine

Comment: You should check that `ls` is on the path from within whatever environment Nagios is running in.  It may be different than the command line path.